# Fractional Max-Pooling: a Deep Neural Network I find difficult to implement

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Based on the paper Fractional Max-Pooling by Benjamin Graham, I've tried to write the network code with the CIFAR-10 data-set:

(160nC2−FMP3√2)12−C2−C1−output

but after python parses:

```
import numpy
import keras
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Conv2D,Conv1D,LSTM
from keras.layers.core import Reshape
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling1D
from Fractional_MAXPOOL import FractionalPooling2D
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
#K.tensorflow_backend.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

# load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

X_train = X_train[0:49984]
y_train = y_train[0:49984]
X_test = X_test[0:9984]
y_test = y_test[0:9984]

# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0.0-1.0
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train = X_train / 255.0
X_test = X_test / 255.0

# one hot encode outputs
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]

# print("num_classes = " + str(num_classes))

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(160, (2, 2), batch_input_shape=(64, 32, 32, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(FractionalPooling2D(pool_ratio=(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1),pseudo_random = True,overlap=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))

# Block 2
model.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

opt = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(0.1,decay=1e-4)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('Model.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only = True, verbose=1, mode='min')

callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
#model.load_weights('Model.hdf5')
epochs = 1000
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = [X_test,y_test], nb_epoch=epochs, batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

keras/tf gives me the following error:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (49984, 10)

Comment: you should `flatten()` your input before feeding into the last dense layer

Comment: @Shubham Shaswat : I've tried but it gives me another error:
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Comment: is this the full model or there are some layers that you don't write here

Comment: It's is a synthesis, just the last layers. I cand send the full code to you, if you would like to inspect it.

Comment: We don't use email here, stop offering to email code. The problem is now that your input is a 3D array, while you told keras it should be a 4D array with shape (64, 32, 32, 3)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see other ways to share code.

Comment: Just put it in your question, you can always edit your own question.

Comment: Ok, I've undestood. There's the code.

Comment: There is a Conv1D near the end of your network, it should be a Conv2D

Comment: I've tried with Conv2D: model.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2), padding='same'))
but I still have the same error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (49984, 10)

Comment: Anyway, the original article say explicitly (for the network I'm testing) that the layer before the output is a Conv1.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. First is not flattening the features (this produces the error about the targets), and a stray `Conv1D` layer that should be a `Conv2D`:

```
# Block 2
model.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

With these changes the model should be able to train. You also have to import `Flatten`.

Comment: My python complaints on line `model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))`:
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 0 for 'conv2d_14/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [64,0,0,128], [3,3,128,64].

Comment: @FilippoPortera Then you should tune the hyperparams, like kernel size and padding in order to prevent this, as the feature maps are probably very small by that layer due to the depth of the network.

Comment: I've tried what you said and I'm still getting errors.

Comment: @FilippoPortera Without details I cannot really say more, its a different problem than the one in your question.

Comment: I've tried with kernel_size=1:
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 1 from 0 for 'conv2d_14/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [64,0,0,128], [1,1,128,64].

Comment: @FilippoPortera use padding='same'

Comment: I've tried adding padding='same':
ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (0, 0, 64)). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.

Comment: Sorry, but don't you have the full source by now?